# WPF - Binding on ancestor two differents views

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've got four views, the first which is a `Window` that contains a `ComboBox`, for every item in  my `ComboBox` I got three different types so I just made three different little view for each type of items.

My problem is, I can't bind my text value with ancestor current item in my mainview. When I try to bind on the list/CurrentItem my program crash.

the list in the Main view:

```
<GroupBox Margin="5,5,10,5" Grid.Column="1" Header="MyListOfTypes" Name="MyListOfTypes">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyListOfTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedType}" />
        </GroupBox>
```

my textbox in the little view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Editeur.View.BaliseFixView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="28" d:DesignWidth="240">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Fix :" />
        <TextBox Width="170px" Grid.Column="1" Name="fixValue" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Balise.MyListOfTypes/}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The locator:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<BaliseViewModel>();
        }

        public BaliseViewModel Balise
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<BaliseViewModel>();
            }
        }
    }
```

**SOLUTION**

Fixed by adding a propertie:

```
public string Valeur
{
    get
    {
        return _valeur;
    }
    set
    {
        Set(() => Valeur, ref _valeur, value);
    }
}
```

And a function

```
public void RemplirDicoVars(XDocument document)
{
    ApercuValeurs = (
        from p in document.Descendants("apercu")
        select new
        {
            Key = (string)(p.Attribute("var")),
            Value = (string)(p.Attribute("value"))
        }).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Width="170px" Grid.Column="1" Name="fixValue" Text="{Binding Path=Valeur}" />
```

Comment: Check the output window, are you getting any error message there?

Comment: yes : Une exception de première chance de type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' s'est produite dans mscorlib.dll

Comment: Edited the main post with my actual binding.

Comment: Whats is "locator"?  Might be helpful if you provide a full code listing for both of the views

Comment: Locator is mvvm model construction politic. The main problem is why i can't get the currentItem from the ancestor view of the view that contain the textbox. Added the locator in the main post.

Comment: Cleaned the main post, added the complete little view code.

Comment: Where are you setting the current item? And how does your BaliseViewModel look like(not the full, the important parts like declaration, constructor and the property)?

Comment: BaliseViewModel got public ObservableCollection<IBalise> MyListOfTypes{ get; set; }. the constructor have got an XElement node in parameter, affect My Propertie Node with the param node (Node = node) and create new instance of MyListOfTypes. That's all

Comment: FIXED. (can't post solution i haven't got 10 reputation) need to wait 8h